# JavaScript getElementById(...) is null or not an object IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

This must be something very simple for the JavaScript experts out there. In the following code, I am trying to open an iframe to the full height of browser window.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function resizeIframe() {
    var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    height -= document.getElementById('documentFrame2').offsetTop;
    height -= 20;
    document.getElementById('documentFrame2').style.height = height +"px";
 };
document.getElementById('documentFrame2').onload = resizeIframe;
window.onresize = resizeIframe;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <iframe src="standard-tube-map.pdf" id="documentFrame2" width="100%" onload="resizeIframe();" ></iframe> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It works in Mozilla but in IE (only tested in IE8) it gives the error: 'document.getElementById(...) is null or not an object'. Can anybody suggest what should I change to make it work cross browser?

Many thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do

```
document.getElementById('documentFrame2').onload = resizeIframe;
```

before the document is ready so the iframe can be found. call this in the onload- or document-ready-function or in a seperate javascript-block after the iframe.

Comment: Just removed the script from <head> and placed it inside <body> after the <iframe> and it worked. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping

```
document.getElementById('documentFrame2').onload = resizeIframe;
```

Within:

```
window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById('documentFrame2').onload = resizeIframe;
    window.onresize = resizeIframe;
    resizeIframe();
};
```

The iframe doesn't exist in the DOM until the page/Dom has loaded.

**UPDATE**:

Didn't see part of the code you posted.

You could keep `onload = "resizeIframe"` within the element itself and have the JavaScript in the head as:

```
function resizeIframe() {
    var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    height -= document.getElementById('documentFrame2').offsetTop;
    height -= 20;
    document.getElementById('documentFrame2').style.height = height +"px";
 }


 window.onresize = resizeIframe;
```

That way you wouldn't need any JavaScript running after the element.

Comment: Thanks Tomgrohl. After trying this, there is no error in the status bar, but the size of iframe is the default.

Comment: Much appreciate your effort, but its still not working for me in IE. It only becomes full height when I resize the window. Is there any other workaround?
Thanks again.

Comment: On page load you could get it to run resizeIframe(). That would solve it. I've edited my answer as it was easier so check that.

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   alert(document.getElementById('abcId').value);
   ```
2. ```
   alert(document.formName.elements['abcName'].value);
   ```

I expirienced the same issue i tried the 2nd one it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `onload"resizeIframe"` in the iframe tag, you don't need `document.getElementById('documentFrame2').onload = resizeIframe;` anymore

I prefer relacing `window.onresize = resizeIframe;` by:

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.onresize = resizeIframe;
};
```

Sometimes the window will be resized before the iframe is ready for operation, and that would cause errors.

========================

edited:

```
window.onload = function() {
  resizeIframe();
  window.onresize = resizeIframe;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, but this is only working if you resize the window.