# document.getElementByID(...) is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I'm having the exact same problem as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147556/javascript-getelementbyid-is-null-or-not-an-object-ie) (IE8 is telling me that `'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object`, but every prescribed answer (including the accepted answer that worked for the OP) is some variant of "the DOM isn't ready; wrap your code in an onload callback."

Problem is, that's not doing the trick for me. The code has always lived inside `$(document).ready(...)` and hasn't been modified in approximately 22 months, during which time it has worked consistently despite changes around it. "All of a sudden," it's throwing this error.

The code has worked (and continues to work) in all other browsers - and again, has always worked in IE8 until very recently (we just noticed the issue this morning). I have to believe this was caused by some other markup or scripting change, but I can't imagine what could have possibly caused this breakage. Where can I start looking?

Comment: Can you share more code (or even url) , please?

Comment: Start looking if the element with that ID still exists. But if you're using jQuery, why are you not using `$("#id")`?

Comment: @OfirBaruch: Unfortunately not. I'll try to drum up a small necessary and sufficient example reproducing the issue though.

Comment: @pimvdb: The code works flawlessly in all other browsers, and all markup is static (i.e. not server generated).

Comment: I won't be surprised if it's an IE8 bug...

Comment: @pimvdb: Also, we are using jQuery elsewhere - this is legacy code.

Comment: Remove everthing from the page apart from the `getElementById` call and the element in question, run the page, if it works then just start putting everything back in, one part at a time and test the page. This should narrow it down.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm voting to close. I haven't been able (thus far) to reproduce the issue with sample code, and I'm unable to post the full page/assets for reference (legal reasons).

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is an element with the correct id (case-sensitive!) and check that the id is unique as it should be (no other elements with that id should exist on the page).

Comment: The ID (casing and all) is correct and unique.

Comment: Then I'd need sample code to debug this. If there is other javascript code that alters the page before your code runs (change id / remove element), than that can be the problem.